# Why is my div not horizontally centered?

Tags: css, center, margin

I have two divs horizontally aligned next to each other, each taking ~50% of the page width. Now if the browser window changes, my I want to keep one div centered (`<div id="featured">`) but it doesn't, even tho I set  `margin: 0 auto;`) How can I keep it centered in its area (right side of the 50%)?
link: http://spabc.com/drupal

Comment: seems to stay on the center of the right 50% of the page using chrome!

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Aram WOW< I'm just realizing that Chromium renders the page completely different from Chrome. Wow, why are the four images not on the same height as the text block on the left...? :o Scarry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or if you want the images right next to the div on the left you can position absolute it and then use margin left on the images. Hope this helps.